# How do you plot nonlinear quadratic system?

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-functions, quadratic-programming

Consider the following system of two nonlinear (quadratic) equations with  =
0.400256 and  = 0.916403.

− +  −  + ^2 = 0

− +  +  − ^2 = 0

Plot the two implicit equations and observe that there are two solutions: one at the origin
and the other one close to (1.3, 0.8).

Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
a=0.400256;
b=0.916403;
f = @(x) [-x(1) + a*x(1) - b*x(2) + b*x(1)^2];
f2 = @(x) [-x(2) + b*x(1) + a*x(2) - a*x(1)^2];
ezplot('f',[-10 10 -10 10]); hold on;
ezplot('f2',[-10 10 -10 10]);
grid
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not for homework questions.  It's important to think through these problems and try to find a solution yourself.  If you run into programming problems then we are here to help, not to do your homework.

Comment: Post any errors received thus far.

Comment: That's better, but what is your specific question?  Have you hit an error, or trying to do something that isn't working?

Comment: Whenever I plot it, it shows only one line (both equations over each other). How do I show two quadratic functions separately but on one graph?

Sorry I am new to MATLAB @THeron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track, but didn't defined the functions properly.

```
a=0.400256;
b=0.916403;
f1 = @(x,y) -x + a*x - b*y + b*x.^2;
f2 = @(x,y) -y + b*x + a*y - a*x.^2;
ezplot(f1);
hold on
ezplot(f2);
```